# Example of mesh using EvaluateTx

Tags: mesh

Can anyone link an example of mesh handling a tx with a plutus script requiring the calculation of fees?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

https://meshjs.dev/providers/tangocrypto#evaluateTx

https://meshjs.dev/providers/ogmios#evaluateTx

Comment: I'm looking for examples using these functions